# How to sum each user totals per category

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

[table preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvPC0.png)

I have the above table which I'd like to sum all users total per category. Totals for user 1, User 2, ..., user 20 to be shown at the end of the table. how can i achieve this in Joomla?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Seriously consider normalising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: Got a solution for this..

    `public function getTotalsx($user = 'user_1'){
     $db    = $this->getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);

     // Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
     $query->select(array('SUM('.$user.')'));
     $query->where('catid = 1');

     $query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name'));
  
     $db->setQuery($query);

     $results = $db->loadResult();

     return $results;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
SELECT `Category_ID` ,SUM( `user1` ) AS user1, SUM( `user1` ) AS user2 , ...
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY `Category_ID`
```

Comment: Thanks @barney-stinson.. That's really helpful

Comment: Anytime @MichaelBuluma

Comment: I've run into another issue on implementing this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS). 

This is my current code:
$query->select($db->quoteName(`catid` ,SUM( `user_1` ) AS user1, SUM( `user_2` ) AS user2, SUM( `user_3` ) AS user3, SUM( `user_3` ) AS user3, SUM( `user_4` ) AS user4, SUM( `user_5` ) AS user5, SUM( `user_6` ) AS user6, SUM( `user_7` ) AS user7, SUM( `user_8` ) AS user8, SUM( `user_8` ) AS user8, SUM( `user_9` ) AS user9, SUM( `user_10` ) AS user10);